# Retornarlo dependiendo de la opción elegida en sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

Buen día,  necesito con sweetalert2 que al hacer click en si retorne true y en cancelar retorne false, lo que pasa al probar con debug veo que sale el mensaje y sale de la función que usa y no llega a retornar nada en precomfirm y en then.

```
function verificarValidacionFormaPago(formaPago){
      switch(formaPago){
          case 'S': return true; break;
          case 'N' :return false; break;
          case 'X':{
                     Swal.fire({
                        title: 'un titulo',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                       showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                       preConfirm: (isconfirm) => {
                       return isconfirm ? true: false}
                      }).then(response => {
                      if (response.value) {
                        return true;
                      }ese{
                         return false;
                        }
                   });
           }
      }
 }
```

Llamo a la función verificarValidacionFormaPago y cuando la forma de pago es X muestra el mensaje pero sale del switch y termina la función y no retorna nada. El mensaje sigue mostrándose aprietas en si o cancelar y ahí entra al precomfirm o al then pero ya la función terminó sin retornar nada.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, para hacer eso solo tienes que retornar la funcion `Swal.fire();`, ya que esta es una función, ella retornará un valor y para retornar el valor dentro de otra función, tienes que retornar a la función. Ahorita con el ejemplo verás de lo que hablo.

Solo decir que debes tener en cuenta que las funciones de SweetAlert retornar un `Promise`, por lo tanto la respuesta será asincrónica.

Sin más que decir, te dejo el ejemplo ya resuelto:

```js
// app.js

function verificarValidacionFormaPago(formaPago) {
    switch (formaPago) {
        case 'S': return true; break;
        case 'N': return false; break;
        case 'X': {
            return Swal.fire({ // retornando lo que retorne la función Swal.fire(); (retorna una Promise)
                title: 'un titulo',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: (isConfirm) => {
                    return isConfirm; // Si el usuario dió click en 'sí', se retornará true.
                }
            }).then(response => {
                Swal.close();
                return response.value; // En caso de haberse clickeado cancel, retornará 'undefined' que es lo mismo que false en cuanto a interpretación booleana.
            });
        }
    }
}

var a = verificarValidacionFormaPago('X');
if (a instanceof Promise) { // Validando si lo retornado por verificarValidacionFormaPago() es una promesa (caso 'X');
    a.then(response => {
        alert(response ? 'Confirmed :)' : 'Canceled :(');
    });
} else {
    alert(a ? 'Confirmed :)' : 'Canceled :(');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StackOverflow example</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahí lo modifique para tener un poco más de info , Llamo a la función verificarValidacionFormaPago y cuando la forma de pago es X muestra el mensaje , pero sale del switch y termina la función y no retorna nada. El mensaje sigue mostrándose aprietas en si o cancelar y ahí entra al precomfirm o al then pero ya la función terminó sin retornar nada.

Comment: @EzeQuevedo ya edité mi respuesta para responder a tu pregunta.